Python in Excel: How to access the records of a JSON file imported using Excel Query
I have a deeply nested JSON file that I have imported using Power Query into Excel and Microsoft 365 using
Data>Get Data>From File>From JSON
It loads into a [Record].
I would like to access and process this loaded object using Python in Excel.
I have a manual workaround of loading the JSON as a single string into a single cell and then processing. This works, but using queries to first load the file would give more control and circumvent 32K character limits for single cells.

Can you provide a [example]? It could help us see if we have the expertise to answer your question.
